# Ping-visible on unlock, ping-muted on screen lock

Tags: windows-7, script, powershell, ping

When I login to / unlock my Windows 7, I need to switch the machine to ping-responsiveness mode.

When I pres Win-L key, i.e. lock the machine, I need it to ignore ICMP pings.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: No, I need to trigger an action on other machine

Answer (score 1):

I would use this registry bit to disable win+L functionality.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableLockWorkstation"=dword:00000001
```

Then we can re-assign win+L to run a custom batch script that disables ping followed by locking the machine. Combine that with a login script that re-enables ping upon unlock/logon.

Or we could leave win+L alone and just start the batch script with a different key combo.